# Button Text Change on Every Click in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#

- on button first click text of button should be "01" via below method "m1"
- on button second click text of button should be "02" via below method "m2"
- and on third click "01"
- again on forth click "02"
- and so on so forth

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

public void m1()
{
    button1.Text = "01";
}

public void m2()
{
    button1.Text = "02";
}
```

Comment: is this asp.net? if so, please add more details to the question and tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Boolean b = true;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (b)
        {
            m1();

        }
        else 
        {
            m2();

        }
        b = !b;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
public bool dirtyBool = true; //Initialize it on contructor
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dirtyBool)
    {
        button1.Text = "01";
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Text = "02";
    }
    dirtyBool = !dirtyBool;
}
```

and if you want to call the function than

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dirtyBool)
    {
        m1()
    }
    else
    {
        m2()
    }
    dirtyBool = !dirtyBool;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Text == "01" ? m2() : m1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
   private bool isEvenClick;
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isEvenClick)
        {
            m1();
            isEvenClick = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m2();
            isEvenClick = false;
        }
    }

    public void m1()
    {
        button1.Text = "01";

    }

    public void m2()
    {
        button1.Text = "02";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods m1 and m2 appear to be private but marked public. This can be accomplished by counting the number of clicks. If this is asp.net, the number of clicks should be stored in database or session. If this is WPF, the number of clicks can be stored in a static variable. The code should look like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int numOfClicks = GetClickCount();
  button1.Text = numOfClicks % 2 == 0 ? "02" : "01";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        count++;   //increment the variable on every button click that is declared globally 
        if(count%2==0)//checking the condition
            m2();//calling the method if the condition is true
        else  m1(); //else calling another method

    }
    public void m1()//method1
    { button1.Text = "01";}      
    public void m2()//method2
    {button1.Text = "02";}

}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answers to help future users.